# Bluebird shows broken stacktrace when using with Sequelize/MySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, bluebird

I am using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) promises, and [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) (which internally also uses bluebird) on Node.

Right at the beginning I do this:

```
// only use one Promise library for the entire application
GLOBAL.Promise = Sequelize.Promise || require('bluebird');
// setup long stack traces
GLOBAL.Promise.longStackTraces();
```

Most of the time, I get fine stacktraces. But sometimes when I get an error from Sequelize's underlying MySQL implementation, stacktraces bug out, like so:

```
SequelizeUniqueConstraintError
    at module.exports.Query.formatError (D:\code\theapp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:109:16)
    at Query._callback (D:\code\theapp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:38:23)
    at Query.Sequence.end (D:\code\theapp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\code\theapp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:93:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\code\theapp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:271:23)
    at Parser.write (D:\code\theapp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (D:\code\theapp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous    (D:\code\theapp\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:82:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous    (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9) 
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event:
From previous event: (D:/code/theapp/components/util/Log.js:116)
```

I am running Node v0.10.33 on Windows 7.

Is this a bug? And if so, with which library (or with Node?) should I file it?

Comment: Some possibly related threads: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8199 | https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12044

Answer (score 2):

I did some more digging and found that this particular error is a custom Sequelize error which, in it's constructor, calls further custom error constructors, all the way down a chain to `Error.apply(this, arguments)`. This error also wraps the original error. If instead of the wrapper, I obtain the native error (that was not created through `Error.apply`), even if I only read it once (like `var smth = err.theWrappedError && err.theWrappedError.something;`), the correct stacktrace appears. So I assume, this, like previous stacktrace mysteries, is probably a V8 bug.

For reference, this code caused above buggy stacktrace:

```
if (!message) {
    message = 'exception';
}
console.error(message = this.Tools.formatUserMessage((message && (message + ' - ') || '')));
console.error(err.stack);
```

This code shows much more information and a correct stacktrace:

```
var parent = err.parent;    // access the underlying error here
var sql = (parent && parent.sql) || err.sql;
var sqlMessage = sql && 'SQL error `' + sql + ']';
if (!message) {
    if (sql) {
        message = sqlMessage;
    }
    else {
        message = 'exception';
    }
}
else {
    message += ' - ' + sqlMessage;
}
console.error(message = this.Tools.formatUserMessage((message && (message + ' - ') || '')));
console.error(err.stack);
parent && parent.stack && console.error(parent.stack);
```

Two things:

1. Eventually, you probably want to make this fully recursive and keep going up as long as there is another `parent`, even though I have not seen error chains longer than two yet.
2. Even though the correct error trace will be revealed by `err.stack`, it can't hurt showing the whole thing.

Example stacktrace from the second code snippet:

```
[2015-01-30 17:09:13.235] [ERROR] default - [asd] SQL error (`INSERT INTO `theApp_user` (`uid`,`role`,`displayRole`,`name`,`locale`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,4,4,'asd','en','20109:13','2015-01-30 09:09:13');`) -  (D:/code/theApp/components/util/Log.js:126)

[2015-01-30 17:09:13.237] [ERROR] default - SequelizeUniqueConstraintError
    at module.exports.Query.formatError (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:109:16)
    at Query._callback (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:38:23)
    at Query.Sequence.end (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:93:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:271:23)
    at Parser.write (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:82:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
From previous event:
    at new Promise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:84:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:28:17)
    at module.exports.Query.run (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:31:19)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:20
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:66:18)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
From previous event:
    at new Promise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:84:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:28:17)
    at ConnectionManager.getConnection (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:186:10)
    at module.exports.Sequelize.query (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:610:85)
    at module.exports.QueryInterface.insert (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\query-interface.js:451:27)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance.js:601:43
From previous event:
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance.js:578:25
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:66:18)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
From previous event:
    at module.exports.Instance.save (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance.js:500:23)
    at module.exports.Model.create (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1051:8)
    at Object.Private.createAndLogin (D:\code\theApp\components\models\core\User.js:339:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\code\theApp\components\debug\CourseSimulator.js:440:55)
From previous event:
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\code\theApp\components\debug\CourseSimulator.js:415:47)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:66:18)
From previous event:
    at Promise$bind [as bind] (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:104:9)
    at Object.Public.reset (D:\code\theApp\components\debug\CourseSimulator.js:390:22)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\lib\CommandProxy.js:129:74
    at tryCatcher (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:4408:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:2342:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:2504:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAtPostResolution (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:2070:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:152:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:157:10)
    at Async.drainQueues (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:82:14)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
From previous event:
    at new Promise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:84:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:28:17)
    at ConnectionManager.releaseConnection (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:196:10)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:615:39
    at Object.finallyHandler (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\finally.js:64:23)
From previous event:
    at new Promise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:84:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:28:17)
    at module.exports.Query.run (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:31:19)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:20
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:66:18)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
From previous event:
    at new Promise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:84:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:28:17)
    at ConnectionManager.getConnection (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:186:10)
    at module.exports.Sequelize.query (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:610:85)
    at module.exports.QueryInterface.insert (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\query-interface.js:451:27)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance.js:601:43
From previous event:
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance.js:578:25
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:66:18)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
From previous event:
    at module.exports.Instance.save (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance.js:500:23)
    at module.exports.Model.create (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1051:8)
    at Object.Private.createAndLogin (D:\code\theApp\components\models\core\User.js:339:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\code\theApp\components\debug\CourseSimulator.js:440:55)
From previous event:
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\code\theApp\components\debug\CourseSimulator.js:415:47)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:66:18)
From previous event:
    at Promise$bind [as bind] (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:104:9)
    at Object.Public.reset (D:\code\theApp\components\debug\CourseSimulator.js:390:22)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\lib\CommandProxy.js:129:74
    at tryCatcher (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:4408:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:2342:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:2504:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAtPostResolution (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:2070:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:152:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:157:10)
    at Async.drainQueues (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\nogap\assets\bluebird.js:82:14)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13) (D:/code/theApp/components/util/Log.js:127)

[2015-01-30 17:09:13.240] [ERROR] default - Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'asd' for key 'theApp_user_name'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:48:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:82:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:271:23)
    at Parser.write (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:82:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:528:21)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:135:48)
    at Connection.query (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:185:25)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:32:23
    at sequelizeResolver (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:32:12)
    at tryCatch2 (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:53:21)
    at Promise$_resolveFromResolver [as _resolveFromResolver] (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:618:13)
    at new Promise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:84:37)
    at new SequelizePromise (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:28:17)
    at module.exports.Query.run (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:31:19)
    at D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:20
    at tryCatch1 (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:45:21)
    at Promise$_callHandler [as _callHandler] (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:660:13)
    at Promise$_settlePromiseFromHandler [as _settlePromiseFromHandler] (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:675:18)
    at Promise$_settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:845:14)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\code\theApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\promise.js:66:18) (D:/code/theApp/components/util/Log.js:128)
```

**UPDATE**

Actually I found that this work sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't, and sometimes it works partially (partial stacktrace shown)... Maybe a race condition in V8 stack or heap manager...